# PHP, compare two arrays then create a third array with the results

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I have a array with values based on a specific player and I want to use some of these values(match_id and minutes) to compare to a second array and then create the third array to hold the returned values.

I'm writing this for a Joomla based website and so I'm using an inbuilt array functions LoadRowList(); which returns an indexed array of indexed arrays from the table records returned by the query.

The first array contains values populated based on a particular player

```
$search = array();
                $query = "SELECT first_name,match_id,m_name,minutes,points
                          FROM #__bl_players as pl,#__bl_match_events as me,#__bl_matchday as md, #__bl_match as m
                          WHERE pl.id = me.player_id
                          AND pl.id = ".$player_id."
                          AND me.match_id = m.id
                          AND m.m_id = md.id
                          ";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $search = $db->loadRowList();
```

The $search array outputs an array in the format below. print_r($search);

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [0] => Marco [1] => 33 [2] => Xornada 04 [3] => 7 [4] => 3 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Marco [1] => 129 [2] => Xornada 08 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => Marco [1] => 129 [2] => Xornada 08 [3] => 6 [4] => 2 ) 
        )
```

The second array contains hundreds of records with the same layout as the first.

```
$data = array();
                $query = "SELECT first_name,match_id, m_name,minutes,ecount
                FROM #__bl_players as pl,#__bl_match_events as me,#__bl_matchday as md, #__bl_match as m
                WHERE pl.id = me.player_id
                AND me.match_id = m.id
                AND m.m_id = md.id
                AND md.s_id = ".$s_id."
                         ";
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $data = $db->loadRowList();
```

The $data array outputs in the same format as above. print_r($data);

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [0] => Pablo [1] => 8 [2] => Xornada 01 [3] => 2 [4] => 3 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Juan Ramón [1] => 9 [2] => Xornada 01 [3] => 1 [4] => 0 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => Pedro [1] => 9 [2] => Xornada 01 [3] => 1 [4] => 3 )
)etc etc etc
```

And finally, I need the third array to be populated by records that are a match between the $search and $data arrays based only on match_id and minutes.

```
    Array(
    [0]=>Array ([1]=> PlayerName(from the first array)[2]=> MatchID[3]=> MatchName[4]=> TimePlayed[5]=> Score(from the first array)[6]=> Score(from the second array)[7]=> PlayerName(from the second array))
)etc etc etc
```

I have revised my original question to include more information I'm no expert so I'm looking for all and any ideas and feedback. Thanks

Note:The column names areas follows Name = first_name, Match ID = match_id, Match name = m_name,The event time = minutes and the Points scored = points

**Issues I'm having**
In response to comments this is my problem take the following code for example (its only an example):

```
$matches = array();
foreach ($data as $entry){
    if ($entry[2] == $search[2]) {
match =$search;
$matches[] = $match
    }
}
print_r($mtaches)
```

If I use a comparison like $entry[2] == $search[2] it will be comparing the 2nd arrays from each ie

```
`[2] => Array ( [0] => Marco [1] => 129 [2] => Xornada 08 [3] => 6 [4] => 2 )
```

==

```
[2] => Array ( [0] => Pedro [1] => 9 [2] => Xornada 01 [3] => 1 [4] => 3 )`
```

so my question is how do you use a type of wildcard so I can compare key values ie

```
$entry[*][2] == $search[*][2]
```

***Thanks to everyone for their help and patience and especially to @erisco for sharing his knowledge***

Comment: You will need `array_walk()` or similar to write your own function - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: I'd prefer a custom process that iterates through the array as opposed to a walk. Less esoteric to read, and possibly more fault tolerant if the input has both numeric and string indeces.

Comment: This problem can definitely be solved with a change in query, but you will need to provide your exact database structure for the involved tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem can likely be solved by a change in query, but without an exact database structure given it is difficult to guess as to what it may look like. If I couldn't change the query, I would solve the problem along these lines.

You want to match based on match_id and minutes, so it would be ideal to have those as indexes.

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [0] => Marco [1] => 33 [2] => Xornada 04 [3] => 7 [4] => 3 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Marco [1] => 129 [2] => Xornada 08 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => Marco [1] => 129 [2] => Xornada 08 [3] => 6 [4] => 2 ) 
        )
```

Changes to:

```
array(
    33 => array(
        7 => array("Marco", "Xornada 04", 3)
    ),
    129 => array(
        1 => array("Marco", "Xornada 08", 2)
        6 => array("Marco", "Xornada 08", 2)
    )
)
```

The same would apply to the second array as well. Then, you can merge them together based on key. If your second array looked like this:

```
array(
    33 => array(
        7 => array("Pablo", "Xornada 04", 3)
    )
)
```

Then the merged version would look like this:

```
array(
    33 => array(
        7 => array(
            array("Marco", "Xornada 04", 3),
            array("Pablo", "Xornada 04", 3)
        )
    )   
)
```

(Whether you throw out non-matches at the time of merging or if you simply exclude match_id/minutes indexes that don't have at least two players later on is up to you.)

Now you can reduce this array to your desired form.

```
array(
    array("Marco", 33, "Xornada 04", 7, 3, 3, "Pablo")
)
```

This is an example of how the transformation could take place.

```
<?php

$one = array( 
    array("Marco", 33, "Xornada 04", 7, 3), 
    array("Marco", 129, "Xornada 08", 1, 2), 
    array("Marco", 129, "Xornada 08", 6, 2)
);

$two = array(
    array("Pablo", 33, "Xornada 04", 7, 1), 
    array("Pedro", 129, "Xornada 08", 1, 0), 
    array("Garcia", 45, "Xornada 01", 2, 2)
);

$three = array();
foreach ($one as $o) {
    $three[$o[1]][$o[3]][] = array($o[0], $o[2], $o[4]);
}

foreach ($two as $t) {
    if (isset($three[$t[1]][$t[3]])) {
        $three[$t[1]][$t[3]][] = array($t[0], $t[2], $t[4]);
    }
}

$four = array();
foreach ($three as $matchId => $t) {
    foreach ($t as $minutes => $tt) {
        // filter out non-matches
        if (count($tt) > 1) {
            $p1 = $tt[0];
            $p2 = $tt[1];
            $four[] = array($p1[0], $matchId, $p1[1], $minutes, $p1[2], $p2[2], $p2[0]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($four);
```

Comment: What you wrote makes sense to me but I need a bit more guidance if I use an inbuilt Joomla function loadAssocList('key') I can return bases on one of the criteria but it doesn't return reliable data because of the keys not being unique. So I'm leaving the Joomla built in function and I want to concentrate on getting this functioning purely with PHP if I was to continue to leave the queries above as they are could you show me how I would return the $data and $search arrays indexed in the form you describe above ie firstly using the match_id as the first key and the minutes as the second. Thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying. You could use a different SQL query, *or* you could transform the data sets you already queried for using PHP. I described each step you could take to arrive at the final data set you want; I simply did not provide the PHP code to do the step by step transformations. I'd be happy to provide the PHP code if it is giving you trouble.

Comment: I appreciate the PHP code to do the transformations this is building on my PHP knowledge. In regards to sql queries I'm open to help there as well but for now can we leave them as is, if after your PHP code addition I'm still battling I'll add all the sql background info to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their help and patience and especially to @erisco for sharing his knowledge

Answer (score -1):

```
$search = array(
    1 => 'PlayerName',
    2 => 'MatchID',
    3 => 'MatchName',
    4 => 'TimePlayed',
    5 => 'Score',
);

$data = array(
    array(
        // match
        1 => 'PlayerName',
        2 => 'MatchID',
        3 => 'MatchName',
        4 => 'TimePlayed',
        5 => 'Score',
    ),
    array(
        // match
        1 => 'OtherPlayerName',
        2 => 'MatchID',
        3 => 'OtherMatchName',
        4 => 'TimePlayed',
        5 => 'OtherScore',
    ),
    array(
        // no match
        1 => 'OtherPlayerName',
        2 => 'OtherMatchID',
        3 => 'OtherMatchName',
        4 => 'OtherTimePlayed',
        5 => 'OtherScore',
    ),  
);

$matches = array();
foreach ($data as $entry) {
    if ($entry[2] == $search[2] && $entry[4] == $search[4]) {
        $match = $search;
        $match[6] = $entry[5];
        $match[7] = $entry[1];
        $matches[] = $match;
    }
}

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply I have revised my question to clarify a bit I hope you can give me some feedback I'm really stuck.

Comment: @CeltaWeb, the technique above is quite valid, even if the specifics didn't run for your code out of the box. You want to build an array of metches based upon a custom criteria.

Comment: @zanlok thanks for showing an interest I have added the issue I'm having to the bottom of the question any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: your idea about wildcards? nothing like that is part of the php language. instead, you use loops. I could post another code example, but the essence would be exactly like what @rik already demonstrated above.

Comment: Yeah no wildcards I was think a bit too much about sql syntax. But if you have time I know it will be similar to @rik but feel free to give me an example of how to compare $data = array(); == $search = array();  using values in their sub arrays. The chunks of code I posted above are actual print_r from the arrays so any help would be appreciated